# Which iOS devices support which version of Open GL ES

Tags: ios, objective-c, opengl-es

Apple's documentation [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/3DDrawing/Conceptual/OpenGLES_ProgrammingGuide/OpenGLESontheiPhone/OpenGLESontheiPhone.html) doesn't provide specifics, unfortunately. Anyone know of a good list of which iOS devices and which versions of iOS support which version of Open GL ES?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

All iDevices can run OpenGL ES 1.0.

OpenGL ES 2.0 is support on both iPad versions, the iPhone 3GS or later, and iPod Touch 3rd generation and later.

As far as iOS versions go, ES 2.0 support was added to iOS 3.x and higher, but only on devices that support it of course.